How to set crypto engine in PKI.js library?
I am trying to set crypto engine, but I am hitting errors.
When I am trying to use import { Crypto } from '@peculiar/webcrypto'
const webCrypto = new Crypto()

this.cryptoEngine = new pkijs.CryptoEngine({ name: 'OpenSSL', crypto: webCrypto })

// @ts-ignore
pkijs.setEngine('OpenSSL', webCrypto)

when doing pkijs.setEngine('OpenSSL', webCrypto) gives me an error:
TS2345: Argument of type Crypto is not assignable to parameter of type ICryptoEngine
Type Crypto is missing the following properties from type ICryptoEngine:
name, crypto, getOIDByAlgorithm, getAlgorithmParameters

When trying to use import * as crypto from 'crypto' from node and trying to construct it like this:
// @ts-ignore
this.cryptoEngine = new pkijs.CryptoEngine({ name: 'OpenSSL', crypto: crypto.webcrypto })
// @ts-ignore
pkijs.setEngine('nodeEngine', this.cryptoEngine)

I get the following error for the first // @ts-ignore
TS2322: Type import("crypto").webcrypto.Crypto is not assignable to type Crypto
The types of subtle.generateKey are incompatible between these types.
Type '{ (algorithm: RsaHashedKeyGenParams | EcKeyGenParams, extractable: boolean, keyUsages: readonly KeyUsage[]): Promise<CryptoKeyPair>; (algorithm: Pbkdf2Params | ... 1 more ... | HmacKeyGenParams, extractable: boolean, keyUsages: readonly KeyUsage[]): Promise<...>; (algorithm: AlgorithmIdentifier, extractable: boolean...' is not assignable to type '{ (algorithm: "Ed25519", extractable: boolean, keyUsages: readonly ("sign" | "verify")[]): Promise<CryptoKeyPair>; (algorithm: RsaHashedKeyGenParams | EcKeyGenParams, extractable: boolean, keyUsages: readonly KeyUsage[]): Promise<...>; (algorithm: Pbkdf2Params | ... 1 more ... | HmacKeyGenParams, extractable: boolea...'.
Types of parameters algorithm and algorithm are incompatible.
Type string is not assignable to type RsaHashedKeyGenParams | EcKeyGenParams
index.d.ts(1900, 5): The expected type comes from property crypto which is declared here on type CryptoEngineParameters

And for the second // @ts-ignore
TS2345: Argument of type CryptoEngine is not assignable to parameter of type ICryptoEngine.
Types of property generateKey are incompatible.
Type
{ (algorithm: RsaHashedKeyGenParams | EcKeyGenParams, extractable: boolean, keyUsages: KeyUsage[]): Promise<CryptoKeyPair>; (algorithm: Pbkdf2Params | ... 1 more ... | HmacKeyGenParams, extractable: boolean, keyUsages: KeyUsage[]): Promise<...>; (algorithm: AlgorithmIdentifier, extractable: boolean, keyUsages: KeyUs...
is not assignable to type
{ (algorithm: "Ed25519", extractable: boolean, keyUsages: readonly ("sign" | "verify")[]): Promise<CryptoKeyPair>; (algorithm: RsaHashedKeyGenParams | EcKeyGenParams, extractable: boolean, keyUsages: readonly KeyUsage[]): Promise<...>; (algorithm: Pbkdf2Params | ... 1 more ... | HmacKeyGenParams, extractable: boolea...
Types of parameters algorithm and algorithm are incompatible.
Type string is not assignable to type RsaHashedKeyGenParams | EcKeyGenParams.

What engine should I be using for the pkijs.CryptoEngine?
